# git push origin master returning Permission denied errors

Tags: git, github

Created a git repository

```
https://github.com/akhetarp/intro-app
```

On the terminal

```
$> git remote add origin https://github.com/akhetarp/intro-app.git 
$> git push -u origin master
```

Returns the following error

remote: Permission to akhetarp/intro-app.git denied to mathanpec.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/akhetarp/intro-app.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

*I am not sure why/how is it identifying me as 'mathanpec'? That is not my user name. In gitconfig i can see the user as arun.khetarpal*

Things i tried: (And no problems were indicated)
a) $>ssh -T git@github.com
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.129' to the list of known hosts.
Hi **akhetarp**! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access

b) Both global and local settings are pointing at my user.name and not at mathanpec

Comment: if it is github, can you just clone it? the origin will be set up for you

Comment: I already have an existing git repository on my local machine.

Comment: @jesses.co.tt : tried it, the same results when i am trying to push back to the repository. Any idea why am i being identified by some other user?

Comment: What does `git remote -v` says?

Comment: git remote -v
origin https://github.com/akhetarp/intro-app.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/akhetarp/intro-app.git (push)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was it was in my keychain on mac. I simply cleaned it and everything worked.

Comment: well what did that entail?